# ADSL with RFC 2684 Bridging

Tags: linux, networking, internet, adsl, pppoe

My new ADSL line is now enabled, I can finally use my Netgear DM111Pv2 to use to the Internet. My ISP has told me a big surprise : I don't need to use a login and a password to connect to the Internet, then I must use the RFC 2684 bridging mode.

It works pretty fine on the ADSL modem's side, but I've spent one night trying to figure out how to connect to the Internet through this modem. I only have a Fonera 2.0n and a computer running Gentoo Linux.

I've been trying to use the br2684ctl utility with brctl on my Gentoo, first I've configured my kernel in that way :

```
CONFIG_PPP=y
CONFIG_PPP_BSDCOMP=y
CONFIG_PPP_DEFLATE=y
# CONFIG_PPP_FILTER is not set
CONFIG_PPP_MPPE=y
# CONFIG_PPP_MULTILINK is not set
CONFIG_PPPOATM=y
CONFIG_PPPOE=y
CONFIG_PPP_ASYNC=y
CONFIG_PPP_SYNC_TTY=y
[...]
CONFIG_ATM=y
CONFIG_ATM_CLIP=y
CONFIG_ATM_CLIP_NO_ICMP=y
CONFIG_ATM_LANE=y
CONFIG_ATM_MPOA=y
CONFIG_ATM_BR2684=y
# CONFIG_ATM_BR2684_IPFILTER is not set
```

And I still get these messages :

```
cirus nais # br2684ctl -b -c 0 -e 0 -a 8.35
br2684ctl[8041]: Interface "nas0" created sucessfully
br2684ctl[8041]: Communicating over ATM 0.8.35, encapsulation: LLC
br2684ctl[8041]: Fatal: failed to connect on socket; No such device
```

The brctl utility keeps telling me "Invalid argument" each time I try to add the nas0 interface into my bridge, I'm honestly hoping I'm doing wrong.

I've been following [this README](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/gentoo-portage/net-dialup/speedtouch-usb/files/README) carefully and this tutorial on [setting up a PPPoE connection with Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=4&chap=3#doc_chap4), but the PPPoE interface just tries to start, and nothing special related to PPP happens, I can't see the interface when I do `ifconfig`.

---

So, I'm asking you if there's something huge I've been missing since the beginning ! Maybe I should wait to buy a new router fully supporting the RFC2684 bridging mode, but I'm more interested in setting up this mode on my Fonera 2.0n and even my Raspberry Pi !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no knowledge of your devices, but the Fonera 2.0n is on the compatibility list of [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).

Configuring the Fonera will be much simpler using a more sophisticated firmware,
but of course flashing a new firmware is always somewhat risky for the router.

See for example this article : [Hacking the La Fonera Fon Router with DD-WRT](http://www.geeked.info/hacking-the-la-fonera-fon-router-with-dd-wrt/).

If the configuration of the router and modem is correctly done,
no special configuration should be required for using the network on any client device.

Comment: Flashing with DD-WRT or another firmware is probably a good idea, but unfortunately, I really can't find any compatible firmware for the Fonera 2.0n as it's using a different chipset. DD-WRT are built for Atheros, since the Fonera 2.0n is using a Ralink one. I think we can forget this router for now.

Comment: There are DD-WRT versions for Ralink, although I haven't managed to locate one. There are also OpenWRT ones, although you may need to compile the firmware (see [here](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=37611)). Maybe the need for compiling also applies to DD-WRT. I agree that buying a new router is much simpler, and I would assure in your place that it is on the compatibility-list of DD-WRT with a simple installation procedure (no special cables or soldering required).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out ! I should work more on my research skills :-) I'll compile it and I will make another reply as community wiki if I can figure out how to use br2684ctl and brctl properly under Gentoo.